# How to copy Nuget packages?

Tags: asp.net-core, nuget-package

I've created  a .net core project (vs2017) in my station.
I need to copy that project into a station which has no internet connection (to download the nuget packages).
The meaning is that I need to copy also all the Nuget packages that the project use.
How can I do it ?

Comment: it is a development environment or deployment environment?

Comment: development environment

Answer (score 1):

This might work. I am not sure this is the right way or not.

Run the following command - `dotnet nuget locals all --list` this will display the nuget package locations in your machine. Copy all the packages from `global-packages` location.

Paste those packages into the other machine. Then either create a NuGet.config file in your solution / root directory or modify global Nuget.config with the location. So next time when you run dotnet restore command, it will look for the new location as well.

Here is an example of nuget.config file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <packageSources>
    <add key="Local" value="C:\ASPNETCore\LocalPackages" />
  </packageSources>
</configuration>
```